# Google maps is going to get replaced? is it true?

Tags: objective-c, ios, mkmapview

I have been working on an application from past 4 months and it's very much depends on Google Maps on iOS platform. Recently one of my friends raised a concern that what if Apple Inc. decides to use a different Map provider?

It turns out after few searching on internet that Apple is going to replace Google Maps with some new advance 3D maps build by company called C3. ([One of the researched resource](http://www.techradar.com/news/software/applications/apple-planning-to-launch-3d-ios-maps-app--1037730)). Well now I am worried of my already written code,

Should I delay my development work until this new technology gets in? or just wait until Apple announces officially.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think we can answer this for you. You'll have to weigh the pros and cons of either action, specifically for the best interests of your business/application and decide. This is a **business decision** (and not a programming one).

Comment: How does this have anything to do with actual programming?

Comment: Pretend he'd asked this: "I'm writing an application, but the underlying platform is unstable, and the API I need to use may change drastically before I release, or even be replaced with a completely different one. Are there any techniques I can use to reduce the impact of platform changes, or should I just give up and wait 'til it stabilises?"

Comment: While this may happen, I can't see it causing much problem. MapKit has been around since the iOS SDK was released thousands, if not millions of apps use it. Any decision by apple to replace it with a completely different API would be dumb. They may introduce an additional 3d map API, but they wouldn't nuke their existing map API without any notice. Conventionally, when Apple replace an API they deprecate the old one, but still keep it around for a while until everyone has had a chance to move forward. You're worrying over nothing, if you ask me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common dilemma in programming, and there's a common solution too. Develop your own primitives - whether you need to display overlays, show landmarks, draw polygons and lines, do everything through stubs in your own code. If the underlying platform has to change, you then have a few well-known places to update to the new API.

Be *very* strict about not accessing the underlying API anywhere that isn't in your wrapper layer, and it should be straight-forward to change to a different later. Not free, of course, but so long as it's possible to implement the primitives you need in the new layer, you just need to change those, and can leave the rest of your project untouched.

It's not worth losing months' of having a finished project to avoid this situation.

Edit: This approach has another benefit - if you end up writing multiple primitive layers for different APIs, you may be able to let the user pick between them: you may have a (more expensive) higher-quality map layer which you charge for, and a cheap/free one which you don't - allowing people free access to a lower-quality version, and letting them buy an upgrade to the better maps. Or ... there are lots of possibilities. It's the same pattern some applications take with data-persistence layers, letting people run the same application on top of differing data platforms. There are lots of examples of this patterm.